# What is Alt+Shift+{?

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

Tested this on CentOS and Ubuntu, if you're in a directory with a ton of files

```
$ ls
day1.tar.gz  day2.tar.gz  day3.tar.gz  day4.tar.gz  day5.tar.gz  day6.tar.gz  day7.tar.gz  day8.tar.gz day9.tar.gz day10.tar.gz
```

And you hit `Alt+Shift+{` it will awk-complete every filename

```
<Alt+Shift+{>
```

completes to:

```
 day{1{0.tar.gz,.tar.gz},2.tar.gz,3.tar.gz,4.tar.gz,5.tar.gz,6.tar.gz,7.tar.gz,8.tar.gz,9.tar.gz}
```

and

```
day1<Alt+Shift+{>
```

completes to:

```
day1{0.tar.gz,.tar.gz}
```

**Questions**: What is this? What is this called? Where is it useful? How can I configure it? Can I do this with for files that end with a substring not begin with one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Bash, it performs the readline function `complete-into-braces`.

Brace expansion is a useful way of abbreviating a reference to multiple files.

For example:

```
ls -l /path/to/dir/*.{c,h}
```

would list all the files that end in ".c" or ".h".

From `man bash`:

> complete-into-braces (M-{)
>                 Perform filename completion and insert the list of possible com‐
>                 pletions enclosed within braces so the list is available to  the
>                 shell (see Brace Expansion above).

and

> Brace Expansion
>          Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be generated.   This  mechanism is similar to pathname expansion, but the filenames generated need not exist.  Patterns to be brace expanded take the
>          form of an optional preamble, followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence expression between a pair of braces,  followed  by  an  optional  postscript.   The preamble is prefixed to each
>          string contained within the braces, and the postscript is then appended
>          to each resulting string, expanding left to right.
>
> Brace  expansions  may  be nested.  The results of each expanded string
>          are not sorted;  left  to  right  order  is  preserved.   For  example,
>          a{d,c,b}e expands into `ade ace abe'.

Completion, by definition, *completes* so it works with files that *begin* with a string.

Comment: I'm amazed.. It is an inverse brace expansion! ... Good one ;) ...